# Show that $\widehat{\delta_{-1} f} = \delta_{-1} \hat{f}$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\delta_a$ be a dilation, such that $\delta_a f(x) = f(ax)$. Let $\hat{f}$ be the Fourier transform of $f$. Also, $E_n$ is a Euclidean space of dimension $n$.

Show that $\widehat{\delta_{-1} f} = \delta_{-1} \hat{f}$.

\begin{align*}
   \widehat{\delta_{-1} f}(x)
   & = \int_{E_n} \delta_{-1} f(t) e^{-2 i \pi t \cdot x} \mathrm{d}t \\
   & = \int_{E_n} f(-t) e^{-2 i \pi t \cdot x} \mathrm{d}t \\
   & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(-t) e^{-2 i \pi t \cdot x} \mathrm{d}t \\
   & = \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(s) e^{2 i \pi s \cdot x} (-1)^{-n} \mathrm{d}s \\
   & \quad \qquad \mbox{with substitution $s = -t$ } \\
   & = \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(s) e^{2 i \pi s \cdot x} (-1)^{n} \mathrm{d}s \\
   & = (-1)^{n+1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(s) e^{2 i \pi s \cdot x} \mathrm{d}s \\
   & = (-1)^{n+1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(s) e^{-2 i \pi s \cdot (-x)} \mathrm{d}s \\
   & = (-1)^{n+1} \hat{f}(-x) \\
   & = (-1)^{n+1} \delta_{-1} \hat{f}(x).
\end{align*}

I need to get rid of that pesky $(-1)^{n+1}$. I've investigated the even-ness and odd-ness of $\hat{f}$, but that doesn't help either. Any suggestions?

Comment: The reason is that you only accounted for flipping the integration limits once instead of n times. You could've avoided this by using multi-dimensional substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot switch between $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$-integrals and $\int_X$-Integrals $(X:={\mathbb R}^n)$ without thinking.

Let $g(t):=f(-t)$ $(t\in X)$. Then
$$\hat g(x)=\int_X f(-t)e^{-2\pi i\> t\cdot x}\>{\rm d}(t)\ .$$Parametrize $X$ by $t:=-t'$ $(t'\in X)$. The Jacobian has absolute value $1$, hence
$$\hat g(x)=\int_X f(t')e^{2\pi i\> t'\cdot x}\>{\rm d}(t')=\hat f(-x)\ .$$